# Permission denied (publickey) error on git run under AWS ubuntu server

Tags: git, ssh

I try to install nginx with git deployment as written here
https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/

But under Ubuntu under AWS.
During installation I created pem fiel and I connect to ubuintu system with ssh.

But pushing to the server with command

```
git push production master
```

I got error

```
root@ec2-NN-NN-NN-NN.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Which step have I to take to make git working ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create non root user :

```
sudo useradd -m nonerootuser
```

with this subdirectores inside of /home/ would be created

copy to /home/nonerootuser/.ssh  config, id_rsa, id_rsa.pub  files from your local server. Or create them

Restart service with

```
 service sshd restart
```

before working with git you need to switch to this user.

```
su -l  nonerootuser
```